# Pass a variable to a Dockerfile from a docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker

I have several docker-compose.yml files that I want to use the same Dockerfile with, with a slight variation. So I want to pass an argument to that Dockerfile so that I can do something slightly different depending on whatever value the variable is set to.

**What I have tried so far**

docker-compose-A.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        - SOMETHING=foo
```

docker-compose-B.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        - SOMETHING=bar
```

I have a dockerfile I want to use SOMETHING in. e.g.

```
# Dockerfile
RUN echo $SOMETHING
```

That doesn't work. SOMETHING is not passed to the dockerfile.

Am I doing this incorrectly or is this not the intended usage?

Is there any other way to pass a variable to a Dockerfile from a docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Have you introduced `ARG SOMETHING` in Dockerfile?

Comment: better use ENV, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Comment: @Lauri  excellent! Thanks

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Basically I missed declaring the arg in the Dockerfile.

```
# docker-compose.yml file

version: '2'

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        - SOMETHING=foo
```

```
# Dockerfile
ARG SOMETHING
RUN echo $SOMETHING
```

Shoutout to @Lauri for showing me the light.