# Docker: share private key via arguments

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ssh-keys

I want to share my github private key into my docker container.

I'm thinking about sharing it via docker-compose.yml via ARGs.

Is it possible to share private key using ARG as described here?
[Pass a variable to a Dockerfile from a docker-compose.yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738381/pass-a-variable-to-a-dockerfile-from-a-docker-compose-yml-file)

```
# docker-compose.yml file

version: '2'

services:
  my_service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        - PRIVATE_KEY=MULTI-LINE PLAIN TEXT RSA PRIVATE KEY
```

and then I expect to use it in my `Dockerfile` as:

```
ARG PRIVATE_KEY
RUN echo $PRIVATE_KEY >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
RUN pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/...
```

Is it possible via ARGs?

Comment: Do you want the private key stored in the image or would you like to keep it secret?

Comment: A private key inside the image is discouraged since it's easy to push up to a public registry. Please consider storing this externally, either with a secret, an injected environment variable that's processed by your entrypoint, or as a volume.

Comment: @Matt, I'm looking for more secure solution, but not sure which one is better.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the latest docker 1.13 (or 17.03 ce), you could then use the docker swarm secret: see "[Managing Secrets In Docker Swarm Clusters](https://technologyconversations.com/2017/02/23/managing-secrets-in-docker-swarm-clusters/)"

That allows you to associate a secret to a container you are launching:

```
docker service create --name test \
    --secret my_secret \
    --restart-condition none \
    alpine cat /run/secrets/my_secret
```

---

If docker swarm is not an option in your case, you can try and setup a [docker credential helper](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers).
See "[Getting rid of Docker plain text credentials](https://hackernoon.com/getting-rid-of-docker-plain-text-credentials-88309e07640d#.95gy1gelc)". But that might not apply to a private ssh key.

---

You can check other relevant options in "[Secrets and LIE-abilities: The State of Modern Secret Management (2017)](https://medium.com/on-docker/secrets-and-lie-abilities-the-state-of-modern-secret-management-2017-c82ec9136a3d#.taicgbama)", using standalone secret manager like [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/).

Answer (score 2):

Although the `ARG` itself will not persist in the built image, when you reference the `ARG` variable somewhere in the Dockerfile, that will be in the history:

```
FROM busybox
ARG SECRET
RUN set -uex; \
    echo "$SECRET" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa; \
    do_deploy_work; \
    rm /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

As [VonC notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42801847/1318694) there's now a swarm feature to store and manage secrets but that doesn't (yet) solve the build time problem.

#### Builds

Coming in Docker ~ 1.14 (or whatever the equivalent new release name is) should be the [`--build-secret` flag](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/30637) (also [#28079](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/28079)) that lets you mount a secret file during a build.

In the mean time, one of the solutions is to run a network service somewhere that you can use a client to pull secrets from during the build. Then if the build puts the secret in a file, like `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, the file must be deleted before the `RUN` step that created it completes.

The simplest solution I've seen is serving a file with `nc`:

```
docker network create build
docker run --name=secret \
   --net=build \
   --detach \
   -v ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/id_rsa \
   busybox \
   sh -c 'nc -lp 8000 < /id_rsa'
docker build --network=build .
```

Then collect the secret, store it, use it and remove it in the Dockerfile `RUN` step.

```
FROM busybox
RUN set -uex; \
    nc secret 8000 > /id_rsa; \
    cat /id_rsa; \
    rm /id_rsa
```

#### Projects

There's a number of utilities that have this same premise, but in various levels of complexity/features. Some are generic solutions like Hashicorps Vault.

- [Dockito Vault](https://github.com/dockito/vault)
- [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/)
- [docker-ssh-exec](https://github.com/mdsol/docker-ssh-exec)