# Possible to pass env variable from docker-compose.yml to dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Is it possible to pass an env from an docker-compose.yml file to dockerfile.

I have inside the dockerfile like this:

```
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --env=prod
```

But what I want is when the docker-compose.yml has a build_env that is:

```
environment:
            BUILD_ENV: 'test'
```

Then I want the docker

```
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --env=test
```

How do I achieve something like this? Or are there any other better solutions to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a variable to a Dockerfile from a docker-compose.yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738381/pass-a-variable-to-a-dockerfile-from-a-docker-compose-yml-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass environment variables from docker-compose to container at build stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747843/pass-environment-variables-from-docker-compose-to-container-at-build-stage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can review this documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args

```
build:
  context: .
  args:
    - buildno=1
    - password=secret
    - buildenv=prod
```

-

```
ARG buildno
ARG password
ARG buildenv

RUN echo "Build number: $buildno"
RUN script-requiring-password.sh "$password"
RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod --env="$buildenv"
```