# Single Configuration of exposed ports for a Docker Image, Docker-Compose, and Service Invokation

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, slim

I have a docker-compose.yml file, simplified below

```
slim-first:
  image: slim-image
  expose:
    - 9191

slim-second:
  image: slim-image
  expose:
    - 9192
```

The `slim-image` image comes from a `Dockerfile` that starts a service (using the PHP Slim framework) with the following command

```
#File: Dockerfile

# ...

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:9191", "-t", "/slim/public"]
```

You may have already spotted the problem -- I need to provide PHP's built-in webserver with a port.  However, I'm trying to start **two** services -- each available on a different port.

My Question: Is there a way for me, in my `Dockerfile` to access the `expose`d port values from my `docker-composer.yml` file?

Or is the solution to duplicate the port number into an environment variable that the `Dockerfile` can see.

Or is there some third path that would let me have the port value configured in one, and one place, only?

To clarify, I know I could do something like this

```
slim-second:
  image: slim-image
  expose:
    - 9192
  args:
    - PORT=9192

...

ARG PORT=9191
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:$PORT", "-t", "/slim/public"]
```

but I don't want to repeat the port twice in my docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: [Pass a variable to a Dockerfile from a docker-compose.yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738381/pass-a-variable-to-a-dockerfile-from-a-docker-compose-yml-file)?

Comment: thank you @tgogos -- I do want something like that, but I don't want to have two places in the docker-compose.yml file that needs a port definition.  I added some clarifying comments to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t matter: you can run servers in multiple containers that all listen on the same port, and map them to different published ports on the host.

I would hard-code the port in the Dockerfile; say it’s always port 9191.  Then in the `docker-compose.yml` file you can set

```
slim-first:
  image: slim-image
  ports: ["9191:9191"]
slim-second:
  image: slim-image
  ports: ["9192:9191"]
```

and the two containers will be reachable from different ports on the host.

(EXPOSE in a Dockerfile is mostly documentation; it has two rarely-relevant side effects.  `expose:` in a Docker Compose file doesn’t do much of anything for you at all.)

Comment: Thank you for the attention -- but is this true/accurate?  It's my understanding that if two docker containers are going to talk to one another over their internal network that I need to expose a port on each one.

Comment: I don’t think that’s true on the “new” Docker network setup.  (One of the two things EXPOSE does is set up a port forwarding for `--link` but that’s discouraged these days; just run both containers on the same non-default network.)

Comment: Ah ha, that makes more sense, thank you.  For this particular problem I'm stuck using Docker's old style network settings but I'll definitely keep this in mind when/if I'm doing something greenfield and actually learn how Docker networking works :)